# Combine microphone audio and music from application to pipe to a Slack call

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I wanted to do a little experiment, where I would be able to combine music running in one of my Chrome tabs with the microphone input on a slack call running in the Chrome browser as well, so basically everyone on the call would hear my voice over the background music.

I came across a very good tutorial that sort-of solved my problem but also introduced another one :)

By following the steps described [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/pulseaudio-discuss@lists.freedesktop.org/msg21385.html):

> $ pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=virt_mix
>
> $ pacmd update-sink-proplist virt_mix device.description=VirtualMixer
>
> $ pacmd load-module module-loopback sink=virt_mix

and then in *pavucontrol* app, under Playback, assigning VirtualMixer to the Google Chrome tab which was generating music, and under Recording assigning Monitor of Null Output to the Chrome as well, I basically accomplished what I had in mind. If I play the music and start talking on the micrpohone during the slack call, everyone hears my voice with the music in the background.

However, the problem is now - that I can't hear the music coming from the tab, so the whole point kind of loses the point. Setting Playback to VirtualMixer turns off the music for me, is there a way around this so I can hear it as well ?

Comment: background music during a conference call is absolutely the worst idea ever

Comment: its not really a conference, just a private slack workspace for a few buddies that fool around on a call

Comment: Anyway, I figured out I could just redirect audio from the sink back to headphones, and that works. However, now there is another problem, my mic input is also redirected which is quite annoying, having to hear your own voice.